# best way to test for messages and events using Intern

Tags: intern

can someone suggest the best approach or provide an example on how test for a message or event using Intern?  For instance, I have a Dijit under test which uses topic.publish to send a message and I want check that the correct message was sent.

I'm assuming that I want the topic.subscribe inside a "this.async" section but I can't seem to get the syntax quite right.

Thanks!

--john

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using and it seems to work.  Not sure if it would be better to be using the callback provided by this.async.  Any suggestions/corrections would be much appreciated.

```
'execute method should emit complete event': function()  {
   var myDijit = new MyDijit();

   var dfd = this.async(1000);
   myDijit.execute();
   on(myDijit, 'complete', function(evt) {

   try {
     assert.strictEqual(evt.results.items.length, 83, '83 records expected in response');
     dfd.resolve();
   } catch (error) {
      dfd.reject(error);
   }
 });
}
```